# Spring Boot - React with Material UI

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, material-ui

I am trying to setup a Spring Boot project (Prototype) with React and Material UI.

I followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#react-and-spring-data-rest-part-1) tutorial to get Spring Boot running with React, which went really well! Now, for Material UI I followed [this](https://material-ui-next.com/getting-started/installation/) tutorial. To be more specific, I cd'd into my projects directory and installed the packages via npm.

My app.js file looks like this:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

function App() {
  return (
    <Button raised color="primary">
      Hello World
    </Button>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

And my index.html like this: `<div id="app"></div>`

Then I ran `mvn spring-boot:run`, got no errors and my application started on port 8080.

The only thing I'm seeing though, is a "Whitelabel Error Page". I tried using the `MuiThemeProvider` but I would still get a "WhiteLabel Error Page".

I just want to get a very basic app up and running - I'll figure out the rest while developing.

I'm thankful for any feedback.

**EDIT**
Spring Boot log: https://pastebin.com/gJKh9VFx

Project hierarchy: [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp2G9.jpg)

Setting up a project via [creator](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) works, just without backend.

**EDIT2**

Added a simple controller which now just gives me a blank page without the whitelabel error. Adding some HTML also works, but the Material UI Button still won't render.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: can you post your server log here? woudl be good to know whats the exact reason for showing the whitelabel error page

Comment: Hey! here's my log https://pastebin.com/gJKh9VFx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ditched this approach (where Spring service and client are in one project) and created two separate projects (Rest Service and React Client)

Comment: Is your React App a multi page app?

Comment: Yes. Currently using react router.

Comment: If you don't mind, please share a link to your  live web app.

Comment: Sorry but I can't really do that. You can however create a spring boot application over at [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/), run it and add a proxy in your `package.json` like [here](https://coursework.vschool.io/setting-up-a-full-stack-react-application/). Then you can use something like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to create REST-Actions and use your api. 

It's so much better to just split a project this way.

Comment: The proxy part I mentioned in my previous comment is already outdated - [Here's](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) a new way. I am currently configuring the proxy manually (scroll down).